# How to add search to menu?

Tags: menus, templates, search

How to add search to menu?
I want to have:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);

function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return $items. get_search_form ();
return $items;}
```

in my `functions.php`. But it calls standard search template.
I have created `searchform.php`in my child theme folder.

This part of example, but its hardcoded.

```
return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'>
<form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'>
<input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_search_form/) filter:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
        return $items. get_search_form();

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'custom_search_form' );
function custom_search_form( $form ) {
    ob_start();

    // get_stylesheet_directory will get 
    // the main directory of the child theme
    include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/searchform.php' );

    $form = ob_get_clean();
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I want to use `searchform.php` and don't want keep a lot code in `functions.php`.

Comment: Edited the answer above, it should work fine.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer! Thanks.